# Click 'View more replies' in YoutTube using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the 'View more replies' link in YouTube using python with selenium:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="replies"]/ytd-comment-replies-renderer/ytd-expander/paper-button[@id="more"]').click()
```

but it does not work

Comment: Please your code is short Please add more code to solve the problem

Comment: this is a code to click button